# Geometry data in MSSQL - Bing Maps

Tags: polygon, bing-maps, geometry-conversion, spatial-query, sql-server-spatial

I am pretty new to GIS/Mapping apps. I have obtained some parcel data/tax data and imported it into SQL using Shape2SQL.

The values that I have in the DB are based of the following projection definition.

PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Florida_West_FIPS_0902_Feet",
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",656166.6666666665],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-82.0],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",
0.9999411764705882],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",24.33333333333333],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]

The sample data has values such as:

POLYGON ((713262.40299399942 725948.04824899882, 713242.40249400213 725948.04974899441, 713242.36924400181 725908.74974899739, 713291.95949400216 725908.74599899352, 713291.99174400046 725933.04624899477, 713262.40149400011 725933.04824899882, 713262.40299399942 725948.04824899882))

I get these values by using the geom.STAsText() function.

I am trying to use Bing Maps, which passes in a polygon of Lat/Long Coordinates that represents the bounds of the map. I want to show parcels that are within the bounds of that view (POLYGON ((-82.005076780915289 26.604321062391364, -82.005076780915289 26.586956646764229, -81.964822188019781 26.586956646764229, -81.964822188019781 26.604321062391364, -82.005076780915289 26.604321062391364)))

I am really confused about data types and I can't seem to pull and results from the DB. I am thinking the False Easting is also something I need to take into account.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-project the data before it can be used with Bing Maps. I highly recommend using the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) tool. Here are some useful resources:

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/

White paper and code samples on how to use GIS data with Bing Maps:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AgFqp4QkIjUNloYCwQmwpbyH8dRs6A

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgFqp4QkIjUNk9xph3TWsn4k8M9kzA